# migration SharePoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have the first edition of SharePoint 2010 (no patches) and I need to upgrade it to the 2013 version. When executing this command:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication https://sitename
```

I faced several errors when executing `SQL DDL script` due to the vast differences between the database schemas.

Please give me your suggestions if we need any prerequisite or any things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some steps to migrate from sp2020 to sp2013.
In the end, if you done all rignt, cmdlet Mount-SpContentDatabase correctly upgrade your content database to new schema.

But first of all you need do

1. Check version of 2010 farm to upgrade to 2013. You must have latest service pack for sp 2010
2. Create clean 2013 farm with same passphrase and all accounts. Secure token service will not be migrate withoun same accounts and passphrase
3. Migrate all your app services to save content (for example, metadata service) and create other app services via powershell
4. Migrate content databases to new farm. Before you will mount, run Test-SpContentDatabase cmdlet for check errors

see more [Upgrade 2010 to 2013 sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013)

If you have errors - please, paste here text error message.

Comment: Meaning of that we cannot upgrade without installing the last service pack 2010?  we cannot apply patch on production environment ---  Test-SpContentDatabase result: no error

Comment: There were so far... For migration process exists minimum build version for all upgrades (2007-> 2010, 2010-> 2013, etc). Minimum build version for 2010 is 14.0.6029.1000.
[Sp versions](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224)
[minimum versions](https://vigneshsharepointthoughts.com/2017/02/13/list-of-build-numbers-required-to-upgrade-to-the-next-on-premises-version-of-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command `Test-SPContentDatabase -Name DatabaseName -WebApplication URL` before mount the content DB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/test-spcontentdatabase?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Did you mount the content DB to your web application successfully?

Comment: no many errors are appeared like                                                                           
    :ERROR Upgrade [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] failed. 088c22b6-3e44-4e4f-9cfc-4f56e1dd4d72
11/26/2020 10:03:48.37 powershell (0x2678) 0x117C SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession ajxnm ERROR Inner Exception: Procedure or function proc_SetSiteVersion has too many arguments specified. 088c22b6-3e44-4e4f-9cfc-4f56e1dd4d72

Comment: Please check update status in sp2010 and sp2013 farm. Not enough only install binary files. Also you must check status of content databases in sharepoint 2010 farm. There are no action need must be in status. If not, please run 
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd  installfeatures,
May be you need second update command:
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -passphrase ****** -wait

only clean of errors farms will update correctly